# Opentaps ERP installable file

Tags: erp, opentaps

I have made a Opentaps ERP project. Now I want to install it on clients end. How to install it on client side?

How to make executable file of opentaps (e.g. for android & for iphone)?

Or do we have to install whole opentaps folder as it is (1.25 GB) on client side?

Answer (score 1):

You usually install the entire folder.  The reason why is that big is that you may have the derby database installed with a lot of data.

You should store your version of opentaps in a repository and then clone the repository into the production machine. that way you can always synch and add patches to it

Comment: Can you provide a link/tutorial for configuring opentaps in Windows 7 in Eclipse IDE. I have downloaded the source for OpenTaps and I want to configure this in my machine. I Followed instructions as described here : http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/General_Installation_of_Opentaps. But when I tried to run `ant build` command, it always fails. Why this is so difficult?